# Do functions with asymptotes have inflection points?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Given the function:$$y = \frac {2(x^2-9)}{x^2-4}$$

This function has $x=-2$ and $x=2$ as **VA** and $y=2$ as **HA**, and it doesn't have inflection points. Can I conclude that any function with asymptotes has no inflection point?

Comment: This function has no inflections points and we have no any relation with asymptotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $f(x) = \dfrac{\sin x}{x}$ has $y=0$ as horizontal asymptote and has infinitely many inflection points.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. A counterexample is $y = \frac{x}{x^2 + 1}$ which has three inflection points.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=\frac{x^3}{x^3+1}$ has asymptotes, but $(0,0)$ is an inflection point. There is even else one.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Consider $f(x) = \dfrac{x-1}{x^2}$.